# Reduction of Elapsed time/ User time using parLapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply, elapsedtime

I was trying to evaluate the timings of serial and parallel executions in r. When comparing "lapply" function and "parLapply" functions, I got following results.

```
vec1 <- 1:400000
system.time(result <- lapply(vec1, function(x) x+2))

#using 3 nodes
cl3 <- snow::makeCluster(c("localhost","localhost","localhost"), type = "SOCK")
snow::clusterExport(cl3, c("vec1"), envir = .GlobalEnv)
system.time(clus3 <- snow::parLapply(cl3, vec1, function(x) x+2))
snow::stopCluster(cl3)
```

lapply : user time = 0.69 , Elapsed time = 0.70
parLapply : user time = 0.49, Elapsed time = 0.92

Though user time is reduced, elapsed time seems to be increased. can this be happened or have I done anything wrong? Because I thought that elapsed time should be reduced when using parallel executions.

Answer (score 2):

If your task, calculated on a single node, takes very long time to run, this will be reflected in reduced elapsed times. On the other hand, if the calculation is small, most time will be spent on upkeep (setting up session, moving data, retrieving data...) and nullify or even negate the effect of parallel calculations.